# QGIS - How to add a geometry to an existing feature that has NULL geometry?

Tags: qgis

I have a PostGIS table with some polygons having NULL geometry. The rows are correctly displayed in the attribute table in QGIS. As expected, there is no geometry draw in QGIS.

My question is how can I add a geometry to a row that have a NULL geometry in QGIS. I know I can do some SQL code for that, but I want a end user be able to do this in QGIS.

I have tried different things in QGIS. The logical one for me was to use the tool "Add part" in the advanced editing toolbar. Unfortunately this hasn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: For reference, I logged a bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8459

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug and have since been resolved. For the moment, in the QGIS Dev build only. Works with 2.1.0 (1215d0b), but not 2.0.1.

Reference:
[github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/984](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/984)